# How to reference the value of a form field in the validator or another form field in flutter

Tags: flutter

In the code below, I am trying to test the value of the repeat password against the saved value of the new password field. This value is saved to the variable _newPW. But in the repeat passwords text form field, the _newPW variable is always blank.

How should I do this? I just want to validate that the two new passwords match. Thanks.

```
          TextFormField(
            obscureText: true,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'please enter the new password';
              }
              return null;
            },
            onSaved: (value) {
              _newPW = value;
            },
            decoration: _textFormFieldDecoration(
              hintText: 'new password',
              padding: 8.0,
            ),
          ),

          TextFormField(
            obscureText: true,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'please enter the new password';
              } else if (value != _newPW) {
                print('value = $value');
                print('newPW = $_newPW');           // <-- _newPW variable is blank
                return 'new passwords must match';
              }
              return null;
            },
            decoration: _textFormFieldDecoration(
              hintText: 'repeat new password',
              padding: 8.0,
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `onChanged`

```
onChanged: (value) {
              _newPW = value;
            },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _newPW;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'please enter the new password';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _newPW = value;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _newPW = value;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'new password',
                  //padding: 8.0,
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'please enter the new password';
                  } else if (value != _newPW) {
                    print('value = $value');
                    print('newPW = $_newPW'); // <-- _newPW variable is blank
                    return 'new passwords must match';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'repeat new password',
                  //padding: 8.0,
                ),
              ),
              SubmitWidget(formKey: _formKey)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubmitWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubmitWidget({
    Key key,
    @required GlobalKey<FormState> formKey,
  })  : _formKey = formKey,
        super(key: key);

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          Scaffold.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
        }
      },
      child: Text('Submit'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. Have a great day!